# Using IqualProp in C#

Tags: c#

I want to develop a tool that will assess the quality of a video.  I did some R&D on this and found an interface called "IQualProp", that is part of DirectShow API.  I am not trying to get a sample code in C# on how to use this interface, but i am not finding anywhere.  There are samples in c++ to use this "IQualProp", but not in C#.  Any help on this will be great.

Comment: Chicken-and-egg question, IQualProp is a DirectShow interface.  Everybody uses the DirectShowNet project to tinker with it.  Which already declares the interface, amvideo.cs source file.  DirectShow is very old, pretty unlikely that you actually use it so the interface is of no use to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
IQualProp iqp = your_obj as IQualProp;
```

After doing this you can access all the properties of the interface.